# A Tragic Loss of Documentation of Mathematics History

Tags: discussion

Recently [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txHp-Z3bG3Q) rich piece of the documentation of the history of **The Modern Minds of Mathematics** was discovered to be a casualty of a lack of up-keep by the [IBM Corporation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217720/app-for-minds-of-modern-mathematics-doesnt-work).

My question is what can we, as a community interested in the preservation of Mathematics History, do to try and save it? Or is it beyond the scope of topics this site is willing to address?

Comment: You had me worried there - I thought this was going to be about an archive catching fire or being lost to mildew or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact Eames Office and ask them.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobile/entry/new_app_minds_of_modern_mathematics17

Comment: Thanks for the great link!